# How do I get a more uniform vertical distance between cells?

Tags: swift, layout, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have dynamically created cells using auto layout (no storyboard or xib), but it seems the layout manager is
pairing the cells up so that a short and a tall cell side by side make up a row.

[image: screenshot]

What I want is to have cells with a uniform distance between them (stacked vertically) instead of big empty gaps. So three consecutive short cells going down on the left might be equal in height and position to one large cell on the right. In other words: a uniform distance vertically between all cells.

```
  /// Everything is a side effect.  Configure the cell passed in
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - cell: cell to format
    ///   - indexPath: index of cell
    func formatAutolayoutCell(cell: AutoResizingTextCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let event = eventsSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.layer.borderColor = event.calendar.cgColor
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(cgColor: event.calendar.cgColor).withAlphaComponent(0.1)

        cell.titleLabel.text = event.title

        cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.titleLabel)
        cell.titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cellWidth).isActive = true
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(cgColor: event.calendar.cgColor)
        cell.titleLabel.textAlignment = .center

        cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.bodyLabel)
        cell.bodyLabel.text = event.notes ?? ""
        cell.bodyLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cellWidth).isActive = true
        cell.bodyLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bodyLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Using `Galo Torres Sevilla`'s suggestion I tried using a `UICollectionViewLayout`. It brings me closer to my goal, but it looks like the number of cells is divided evenly by column, so if the leftmost column has short cells, it runs out of cells "early" and the left side has a lot of space at the bottom. It seems likely I may need to sort cells by size to get a better distribution.

[image: second version]

Comment: You won't be able to do this with autoLayout. My suggestion is that you subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and work from there to get the layout that you want. Here is an example that might work for you. https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: That looks perfect. If you want to write this up as an answer in a way that your answer isn't just a link (since link-only answers aren't allowed), I'd be happy to upvote and accept it. You're more than halfway there.

Comment: Excellent job getting your layout! you got it quite fast. I'll leave an answer below

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was already knee deep in the code, so what I read made sense. Plus I was determined to get something working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the code from https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

You can subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout to get what you need.

Here is the main code for it. **Note: Code comes from the website above**

```
import UIKit

protocol PinterestLayoutDelegate: class {
  // 1. Method to ask the delegate for the height of the image
  func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat
}

class PinterestLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
  //1. Pinterest Layout Delegate
  weak var delegate: PinterestLayoutDelegate!

  //2. Configurable properties
  fileprivate var numberOfColumns = 2
  fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 6

  //3. Array to keep a cache of attributes.
  fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

  //4. Content height and size
  fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

  fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
      return 0
    }
    let insets = collectionView.contentInset
    return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
  }

  override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
  }

  override func prepare() {
    // 1. Only calculate once
    guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
      return
    }
    // 2. Pre-Calculates the X Offset for every column and adds an array to increment the currently max Y Offset for each column
    let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
    var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
    for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
      xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
    }
    var column = 0
    var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

    // 3. Iterates through the list of items in the first section
    for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

      let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

      // 4. Asks the delegate for the height of the picture and the annotation and calculates the cell frame.
      let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath)
      let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
      let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
      let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

      // 5. Creates an UICollectionViewLayoutItem with the frame and add it to the cache
      let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
      attributes.frame = insetFrame
      cache.append(attributes)

      // 6. Updates the collection view content height
      contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
      yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

      column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
    }
  }

  override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
    for attributes in cache {
      if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
        visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
      }
    }
    return visibleLayoutAttributes
  }

  override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
  }

}
```